# jQuery CDN and Expression Engine?

Tags: ee2, javascript, jquery, html

We're currently copying the site we developed locally to ExpressionEngine and we are calling all our external libraries via CDN (no server access to upload modules etc). Our jQuery isn't working, however the Foundation 6.4.3 being called referenced via CDN is working. Anyone know if this is a known problem? the CDN script tag is in near the end of the body in our index page before any other jquery requirements (i.e. foundations jquery).

Edit : The sources show that the CDN is loading jQuery and present there, however it's still not applying to the page.
Edit2: Seems that it is only sometimes loading into the sources tab, sometimes it is absent.

Answer (score 0):

99.9% this isn't an EE issue. EE places no restrictions on what you do with external sources.

Sounds like a server/config issue tbh

Comment: Could you provide any more information on this please? (First time using EE) if this was a config issue, would we be able to fix this on the cms panel? If it were a server issue we'd have to just pass it over to the company handling that side since they refuse to give my dev team any access...
I've already removed the installed jQuery module from the cpanel.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).foundation(){}; wasn't being called.